# How can I get the port in my thorntail application from a java class?

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.0, thorntail

How could I get from a java class the port where my application?
For example, with JBoss in standalone.xml I used it is:

standalone.xml

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}" />
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}" />
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}" />
        <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}" />
        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}" />
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712" />
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713" />
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25" />
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>
```

Java class:

```
 Integer port = (Integer) ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer()
                .getAttribute(new ObjectName("jboss.as:socket-binding-group=standard-sockets,socket-binding=http"),
                    "port");
```

Comment: Do you have the `jmx` and `management` fractions? Both might be necessary (not 100% sure if having only 1 of them will suffice.) Alternatively, you can try reading the system property `thorntail.http.port`.

Comment: I try with: 
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>management</artifactId>
        </dependency>

but not working. And I tested too: System.getenv("thorntail.http.port"); and not working

Comment: Weird, adding `jmx` should expose the WildFly MBean server. Can you try connecting to running Thorntail application with `jconsole` and see the MBeans? And it's not `System.getenv`, it's `System.getProperty`.

Comment: For me, It definitely does not work. If I find the solution, I shared it.